# Pause/skip executions of google apps script on Sunday

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, triggers

I have made a Google Apps script project to pick some data from Google Sheets and send on daily basis at a scheduled time. The issue being that, I don't want to execute the script on Sundays. Currently I am handling this via a custom function. The problem with this that, the script at least runs the custom function. I would have liked so that the script skips executions on Sundays. I was looking for a options like **except Sunday** or selection of weekdays from Monday to Saturday in a **checkbox.**

These are the options available as of now in **Week timer**.

[image: Google Apps Script weektimer options]

There is another option in **Select event source** as **From calendar** shown in following image. But I don't think it's useful in this case!

[image: event source as from calendar]

The current code structure is as following.

```
function doGet() {
  if (shouldRunTrigger) {
    var sheetName = "today only"; // Replace with the name of your sheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

    if (sheet) {
      var dataPresent = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(row => row[0] !== "");
      var dataAbsent = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues().filter(row => row[0] !== "");

      var employeesPresent = dataPresent.map(function (row) {
        return row[0];
      });

      var employeesAbsent = dataAbsent.map(function (row) {
        return row[0];
      });

      var emailBody = "Employees present:\n" + employeesPresent.join("\n") + "\n\n" +
        "Employees absent:\n" + employeesAbsent.join("\n");

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "test@test.com", // Add multiple email addresses separated by a comma !!!Not working when put multiple email addresses due to a a feature Google deployed for Spam protection https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585
        subject: "Employee Status",
        body: emailBody
      });
    } else {
      Logger.log("Sheet not found!");
    }
  }
}

function shouldRunTrigger() {
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var date = new Date();
  var day = days[date.getDay()];
  if (day === "Sun") {
    Logger.log(day + "\nNot triggered!");
    return false;

  }
  Logger.log(day + "\nTriggered!");
  return true;
}
```

Is there any feature that I'm not aware of to achieve that? Or any suggestions!

Comment: It seems you can set programmatic triggers for Google Apps. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. It's similar to cron.

Comment: @[Joe Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13100938) and @[Codedabbler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20635660) are correct with what they've said. I also see that your `shouldRunTrigger()` already detects what day it is, so it should work fine for this scenario. Instead of running a custom function, you can set up a [`timeBased()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timeBased\(\)) trigger using [`Class ClockTriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) instead.

Comment: @Codedabbler, thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoeMoore I'm aware of that but thanks!

Comment: @Saddles, thanks for the tip! Will try that!

Answer (score 3):

You can set up an installable trigger in the Extensions.  Create a new file and use a code like this:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
// Trigger function everyday around 6:00 am   
 var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY,ScriptApp.WeekDay.SATURDAY];
for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) { 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('doGet')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(days[i])
      .atHour(6)
      .nearMinute(00)
      .create();
}
}
```

Then Save it and click "Run".  After authorizing the script to run, triggers will be set up for each day of the week.  In the code sample above, the trigger is set to run your script around 6:00 am.  This can be modified as needed.